# How can I stop this useless empty line popping up in the middle of my lists?

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, enumerate, enumitem

My custom `enumerateoptional` enumitem environment is putting a useless empty line in the middle of my enumeration list.

To reproduce this, you need to fill a line 100%. See this example I extracted from my full document, reproducing the problem:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\errorcontextlines 10000
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\def\renewenumerateoptionalitem{%
  \let\itemenumerateoptional\item%
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
      \refstepcounter{enumerateoptionali}% increment the counter
      \itemenumerateoptional[\bfseries##1~\theenumerateoptionali]%
  }%
}

\newlist{enumerateoptional}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateoptional]{
    before=\renewenumerateoptionalitem,
    label=\arabic*,
    nosep,
    align=left,
    leftmargin=*,
    after=\let\item\itemenumerateoptional,
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerateoptional}[1.]
    \item[\bfseries test\_duplicatedContext] Detecção de contextos duplicados e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
    \item[\bfseries test\_duplicatedIncludes] Detecção de inclusões duplicadas  e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
    \item[\bfseries test\_invalidRegexInput] Detecção de expressões regulares 
    inválidas e emissão de um erro semântico.
    \item[\bfseries test\_missingIncludeDetection] Detecção da inclusão um bloco 
    inexistente.
    \item[\bfseries test\_duplicatedGlobalNames] Detecção de múltiplas definições 
    do nome da gramática e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
    \item[\bfseries test\_missingScopeGlobalName] Detecção da falta da definição do 
    nome do escopo global da gramática e emissão de um erro semântico.
\end{enumerateoptional}
\end{document}
```

---

On the following image, the extra new line is between the 4th and 5th item. It is happening because the 4th line is filled 100% the maximum width and latex is putting a extra new line right after it I do not know why.

[image]

How can I stop this useless empty line popping up in the middle of my lists, depending on each item line size?

Comment: Adding an empty line after that item removes the spurious empty line. I'm not sure why that happens, though... Should be something related to the fact that `\item` does a `\par` eventually, but apparently at the time it does it's too late. Adding the `\par` (blank line) earlier works...

Comment: what about the accented letters? maybe some package calculates the dimensions of an `\item` including the accented letters, but the typeset example doesn't inlcude them. Does the output look the same if you replace the text in the source code by `Deteco da incluso um bloco inexistente.`?

Comment: @thymaro, with or without the accented letter, the problem happens the same way. On my full document, I got the accented latter correctly displayed.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, Indeed, I added a empty line before each `\item` and it was fixed. Thanks!

Comment: ok, good, just wanted to make sure it hasn't got to do with that. If you just add lines between your items, the bug is not solved, just ignored. You may move past it, now that it's small and inoccuous, but keep in mind that it might come back later in an evolved state (think Godzilla) to bite your heels (or swallow you whole).

Comment: Really puzzling... I narrowed the issue down to the `hyperref` package only. There is something that is making this weird behaviour. Add a `\par` after the item and the problem goes away. Add a `%` after the item and the problem also goes away. Comment out the `\refstepcounter` line and the problem goes away. Comment out `hyperref` and, you guessed, the problem goes away. Looks like a bug (or at least a quite odd feature) to me...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The blank line you see is a misfeature of your code and `hyperref` making a PDF destination (when you use `\refstepcounter`) at that exact point.

The workaround of adding a `\par` after the text works because the paragraph is built and then the PDF destination is inserted at the beginning of the next line and everything goes well. Adding the PDF destination at the end of the line may cause the destination to go to the next (as far as TeX can see) and then the line seems empty.

An arguably better workaround would be to add `\par` at the beginning of the definition of your modified `\item` command, so that you make sure that the PDF destination is inserted in the correct place.

However the correct way would be to attach the destination to the `\item` itself, so that the PDF destination will *always* be in the right place. One <s>good</s> *bad* place to insert it, is right before printing the value of the counter. As Ulrike said in the comment, the label is typeset in a box (by default), and the `\@currentlabel` is lost (I assumed, incorrectly, that its assignment was global as the counter).

Here's a reworked version which uses a patched version of `\@item` which uses `\refstepcounter` in the right place, and uses a few more `enumitem`

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\user@item\@item
\patchcmd\user@item{\if@noitemarg}{\iftrue}{}{\FAILED}
\enitkv@key{}{formatarg}{\def\enit@format##1{#1}}
% Compatibility with older enumitem.sty:
\@ifundefined{enitkv@enumitem@formatarg}
  {\enitkv@key{enumitem}{formatarg}{\def\enit@format##1{#1}}}{}
\newlist{enumerateoptional}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateoptional]{%
    before=\let\@item\user@item,
    formatarg=\textbf{########1~\@itemlabel},
    nosep,
    align=left,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\makeatother
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerateoptional}[1.]
  \item[test\_duplicatedContext] Detecção de contextos duplicados e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_duplicatedIncludes] Detecção de inclusões duplicadas  e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_invalidRegexInput] Detecção de expressões regulares 
    inválidas e emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_missingIncludeDetection]\label{this} Detecção da inclusão um bloco 
    inexistente.
  \item[test\_duplicatedGlobalNames] Detecção de múltiplas definições 
    do nome da gramática e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_missingScopeGlobalName] Detecção da falta da definição do 
    nome do escopo global da gramática e emissão de um erro semântico. Ver item~\ref{this}.
\end{enumerateoptional}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Also there is no need to restore `\item` in the `after` code (it doesn't harm either) because the `\let` you do is local to the environment, so once it ends `\item` is restored to its original definition.

You also don't need `\bfseries` in every single `\item`: you already use `\bfseries` in the new definition of `\item`.

Comment: Adding `\refstepcounter{enumerateoptionali}` inside the optional argument doesn't work: this is a box and you loose the \@currentlabel and the destination for links. Imho a really sane solution would need a change to the latex \@item command so that it allows to increase the counter even if an optional argument is present (or accepts a second optional argument).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I assumed the assignment to `\@currentlabel` was global too. I fixed it. Thanks :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, after you latest update, the example image is missing the dot `.` after the number (remember the enumitem shortlabel `[1.]` I passed when instantiating the list on `\begin{enumerateoptional}[1.]`). Also, latex cannot build you example anymore. It throws: `main.tex:20: Package enumitem Error: formatarg undefined.` I tested both with MikTek and TexLive 2017.

Comment: @user Oops. Fixed it to take the label into account. The error `formatarg undefined` is probably because you a) didn't copy the line that says `\enitkv@key{}{formatarg}{\def\enit@format##1{#1}}`, or b) forgot to write `\makeatletter` before it. The key `formatarg` is not defined by `enumitem`: I defined it to be a small variation of the `format` key.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, I copied you whole example into a 100% clean new document. I recorded a video proving it to you: https://i.imgur.com/D2xTY5e.gif

Comment: @user A link to the `.log` file would've been enough to spot the problem. You're on TeXLive 2016, and apparently the `\enitkv@key{}{formatarg}{\def\enit@format##1{#1}}` wasn't available at the time, for some reason... I'll check and report back. (One rule about posting answers here is: never trust OP. That's why I asked :-)

Comment: @user With older versions of `enumitem`, you had to do `\enitkv@key{enumitem}{formatarg}{...}`, now the `enumitem` in the first argument is the default and shouldn't be used, that's why I had `\enitkv@key{}{formatarg}{...}`. I updated to work with either version.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, using your latest solution, I got an error while using `\setlist*[enumerateoptional]{any option}`. If I try your first solution, everything works fine with `\setlist*[enumerateoptional]{...}`. I opened another question asking for a fix: [Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@c after using \setlist*\[enumerateoptional\]{nosep}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514708/illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-enitc-after-using-setlistenumerat)