# Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@c after using \setlist*[enumerateoptional]{nosep}

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, enumitem, vertical-spacing

On this question accepted answer [How can I stop this useless empty line popping up in the middle of my lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513020/how-can-i-stop-this-useless-empty-line-popping-up-in-the-middle-of-my-lists), it is defined a new `enumitem` list environment called `enumitemoptional`.

I have been using it so far and no problems, except, when I tried to call `\setlist*[enumerateoptional]{nosep}`, after defining the list initially:

```
test2.tex:24: Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@c
TeX STOPPED: fatal errors occurred. Check the TeX log file for details
```

I am calling `setlist*` and not `setlist` because `setlist` erases all previous settings for the list while `setlist*` keeps them while adding new ones.

I would like to call `setlist*` because I am writing a document class and the `enumerateoptional` is defined inside my  document class. Then, later, the users can call `setlist*` to add custom behaviors as `nosep`.

This is a minimal example, where I am calling `\setlist*[enumerateoptional]{nosep}` after defining the list, and it is throwing the `Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@c`:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\user@item\@item
\patchcmd\user@item{\if@noitemarg}{\iftrue}{}{\FAILED}
\enitkv@key{}{formatarg}{\def\enit@format##1{#1}}
% Compatibility with older enumitem.sty:
\@ifundefined{enitkv@enumitem@formatarg}
  {\enitkv@key{enumitem}{formatarg}{\def\enit@format##1{#1}}}{}
\newlist{enumerateoptional}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateoptional]{%
    before=\let\@item\user@item,
    formatarg=\textbf{########1~\@itemlabel},
    align=left,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\setlist*[enumerateoptional]{nosep}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerateoptional}[1.]
  \item[test\_duplicatedContext] Detecção de contextos duplicados e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_duplicatedIncludes] Detecção de inclusões duplicadas  e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_invalidRegexInput] Detecção de expressões regulares
    inválidas e emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_missingIncludeDetection]\label{this} Detecção da inclusão um bloco
    inexistente.
  \item[test\_duplicatedGlobalNames] Detecção de múltiplas definições
    do nome da gramática e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_missingScopeGlobalName] Detecção da falta da definição do
    nome do escopo global da gramática e emissão de um erro semântico. Ver item~\ref{this}.
\end{enumerateoptional}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatarg key is imho unneeded. The same can be achieved with the standard format key:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\user@item\@item
\patchcmd\user@item{\if@noitemarg}{\iftrue}{}{\FAILED}
\newcommand\mylabelformat[1]{\textbf{#1}~\@itemlabel}
\newlist{enumerateoptional}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateoptional]{%
    before=\let\@item\user@item,
    format=\mylabelformat,
    align=left,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\setlist*[enumerateoptional]{nosep}

\begin{document}\tracingmacros=1
\begin{enumerateoptional}[1.]
  \item[test\_duplicatedContext] Detecção de contextos duplicados e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_duplicatedIncludes] Detecção de inclusões duplicadas  e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_invalidRegexInput] Detecção de expressões regulares
    inválidas e emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_missingIncludeDetection]\label{this} Detecção da inclusão um bloco
    inexistente.
  \item[test\_duplicatedGlobalNames] Detecção de múltiplas definições
    do nome da gramática e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
  \item[test\_missingScopeGlobalName] Detecção da falta da definição do
    nome do escopo global da gramática e emissão de um erro semântico. Ver item~\ref{this}.
\end{enumerateoptional}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, by reverting the question answer to his [first attempt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/513023/1), which uses `before` instead of `formatarg`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\def\renewenumerateoptionalitem{%
  \let\itemenumerateoptional\@item%
  \renewcommand{\@item}[1][]{%
      \itemenumerateoptional
        [\bfseries##1~%
         \refstepcounter{enumerateoptionali}% Advance the counter
         \theenumerateoptionali]% Print it
  }%
}

\newlist{enumerateoptional}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateoptional]{
    before=\renewenumerateoptionalitem,
    label=\arabic*,
    align=left,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlist*[enumerateoptional]{nosep}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerateoptional}[1.]
    \item[test\_duplicatedContext] Detecção de contextos duplicados e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
    \item[test\_duplicatedIncludes] Detecção de inclusões duplicadas  e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
    \item[test\_invalidRegexInput] Detecção de expressões regulares
    inválidas e emissão de um erro semântico.
    \item[test\_missingIncludeDetection] Detecção da inclusão um bloco
    inexistente.
    \item[test\_duplicatedGlobalNames] Detecção de múltiplas definições
    do nome da gramática e
    emissão de um erro semântico.
    \item[test\_missingScopeGlobalName] Detecção da falta da definição do
    nome do escopo global da gramática e emissão de um erro semântico.
\end{enumerateoptional}
\end{document}
```